# PHP / Laravel - Persisting checkbox values to database

Tags: php, laravel

Consider the following **update** form:

```
<form action="{{ $stream->path() }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   @method('PATCH')
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="">
   <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Notes..." name="notes" . 
   </textarea>
   <input type="checkbox" name="data_retention">
   <input type="checkbox" name="perform_ocr">    
</form>
```

Whenever I post this form, I am updating my database in my controller, by using the shorthand and first validating the request, then updating my database.

```
public function update(Request $request, Stream $stream)
{
        //Update the database.
        $stream->update(request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'notes' => 'required|max:255',
            'data_retention' => '',
            'perform_ocr'    => ''
        ]));

        return redirect()->route('streams.show', ['stream' => $stream->token]);
}
```

Now whenever I submit my form, I get below error:

```
General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'on' for column 'data_retention' at row 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

in your html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data_retention" value='1'>
<input type="checkbox" name="perform_ocr" value='1'>
```

in your controller

```
$data_retention =  $request->has('data_retention') && $request->get('data_retention') == 1 ? true : false;
$perform_ocr = $request->has('perform_ocr') && $request->get('perform_ocr') == 1 ? true : false;

$stream->update(request()->validate([
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'notes' => 'required|max:255',
    'data_retention' => $data_retention,
    'perform_ocr'    => $perform_ocr
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

set the values of checkboxs

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data_retention" value='1'>
<input type="checkbox" name="perform_ocr" value='1'>
```

Comment: Problem is, if I then uncheck the checkboxes, and submit the form, it will not update in my database.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the checkbox values in a inline if. If checkbox is selected or not `$data_retention` and `$perform_ocr` will be `true` or `false` and pass that to the database:

```
public function update(Request $request, Stream $stream)
 {
    //Update the database.
    $data_retention =  $request->has('data_retention') ? true : false;
    $perform_ocr = $request->has('perform_ocr') ? true : false;

    $stream->update(request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'notes' => 'required|max:255',
        'data_retention' => $data_retention,
        'perform_ocr'    => $perform_ocr
    ]));

    return redirect()->route('streams.show', ['stream' => $stream->token]);
  }
```

Comment: This in an okay solution, it guarantees a boolean value but assumes that having a value will always imply true. Sometimes you may want to pass the value 0 to imply false but this validation would set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you do something separate from the checkbox itself.

I recommend using JavaScript.

What I think is that you should rename the checkbox to something else. Then name a hidden input field to the original name of the checkbox. Then, if the checkbox is ticked, the value of the input field should be 'off' but if it is on its value should be 'on'.

This code should do  the trick:

```
<form action="{{ $stream->path() }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   @method('PATCH')
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="">
   <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Notes..." name="notes" . 
   </textarea>
   <input type="checkbox" name="data_retention_not" id='data1'>
   <input type="checkbox" name="perform_ocr">   
   <input type='hidden'  name='data_retention id='data2'>
   <script>
   if(document.getElementById('data1).checked){
      document.getElementById('data2').value='on';
}    
else
{
    document.getElementById('data2').value='off';
}
</form>
```

Comment: JavaScript should never be relied on for data validation.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up with below:

```
//Update the database.
$stream['data_retention'] = request()->get('data_retention') ?? 0;
$stream['perform_ocr'] = request()->get('perform_ocr') ?? 0;

$stream->update(request()->validate([
     'name' => 'required|max:255',
     'notes' => 'required|max:255',
]));

return redirect()->route('streams.show', ['stream' => $stream->token]);
```

Comment: Sooo are the other answers still correct.Particularly mine?

Comment: This is not as safe an implementation as Vipul Prajapati's answer, which forces the value to only ever be true/false. This solution allows any string through which could allow SQL injections if not using prepared statements later on.